# NSTextField/NSTextView line size shift while editing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks, nstextview

I have a NSText field with multiple lines and when the field is active (first responder) the line spacing expands slightly while typing and then returns to normal when the field is no longer the first responder. Is there a way to prohibit this behavior, Im dynamically expanding and resizing the field as you type and the increased vertical spacing while editing is causing some issues as well as diminishing the experience. If anyone has any thought's or suggestions I would really appreciate it. I have not been able to find anything about this behavior in the NSTextView class either.

Comment: Exactly the same problem

Comment: looks like a strange issue, because sometimes it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switched to a straight NSTextView. Fixed the issue.